# arpspoof: libnet_init(): UID or EUID of 0 required

Tags: wireless, networking

i'm a new ubuntu user and i'm trying sslstrip .i did all the steps but when i try to run arpspoof i get this error message "arpspoof: libnet_init(): UID or EUID of 0 required"
here is the tuto that i folowed http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/
 help !!!! Thanks (sorry for my english).

Answer (score 4):

You need to run it as root first.I had the same problem. This solved it.

use:

```
sudo -s
```

first.